# TCL Bytecode Loader for TCL 8.4.13?

Tags: compiler-construction, tcl

I've compiled TCL 8.4.13 on a RHEL 5.1 server, however I am in the dark on how to incorporate the TCL loader into this program in order to read and execute compiled TCL code.  I've installed tbcload and TCLPro, however am required to use plain TCL 8.4.13.  Any ideas on how to incorporate the tbcload libraries to work with vanilla TCL 8.4.13?

Answer (score 2):

[Looks like](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tclpro/support/faq.html#Q7.3) you just

```
package require tbcload
# and then
source /the/required/compiled-file.tbc
```

If the compiled code contains a call to some procedure it defines, that's probably all you have to do.  Otherwise you have to figure out which procedure and with which parameters to call after loadling the library, and place a call to that command after the call to `source`.

And while I have no experience with compiled Tcl, I think TclPro itself is not required—to load bytecode you only need to have the loader package (tbcload).

I would also add that sticking to an unmaintained version of Tcl does not look like a very good idea.  I understand that you probably have reasons to use it but if possible, I would try to acquire a version of the code being discussed recompiled for 8.5.x which is probably available for your OS as a regular package with security support from the OS vendor.

Comment: If you're working with tbcload, it's probably worth going for ActiveState's commercial support. If you're doing OSS and so don't want to pay, don't bother with precompiled bytecodes at all as they're slower to load than a plain text script.